# What is the actual advantage of running an AngularJS web app over Node.js instead of a server like Xampp?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, webstorm

As stated in the title,

I don't really understand how Node.js works and **above all** why it's actually used to run an AngularJS application (e.g. in WebStorm IDE this is the default option when you create an AngJS project).

I've got this doubt since I could run a simple AngularJS app on an Apache web server (within Xampp) without any involvement of NodeJS.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js is an application platform.  It's good for running your applications on.

Apache HTTPD is a web server.  It's good at serving web pages.

They're two very different things, not directly related, and not mutually exclusive.

Comment: can you please clarify it? If they're two different things why Nodejs is also a web server which is actually the purpose of Apache? Am I missing some point here?

Comment: @dragonmnl Node.js' built in web server is primarily for returning HTTP responses from your application.  While you certainly could serve static files with it, this is for convenience only and isn't efficient for use in production at decent traffic levels.  If you need to dynamically generate content or handle HTTP requests for something like a RESTful API, then Node.js is great for that.  If you want to just serve files, Nginx and other web servers are a better faster solution.

Comment: @dragonmnl In addition, most people run Node.js behind Nginx or similar.  This allows you to leave all the standard stuff like logging, buffering for slow clients, and bad client interop up to the native application that's fast and good at it.  This leaves your Node.js application to do its job.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that many apps can run anywhere, but some benefits we've seen are:

- Simplicity, especially for web developer also developing the server-side code/config/deploy.
- Real-time web - easier to add in things like WebSockets and Server Sent Events if you need them.